# What's the difference between queue.size() and queue.size

Tags: system-verilog

It seems `queue.size()` can also be written as `queue.size` and it also works. Is there any difference?

Does that mean that all functions and tasks can be used w/o parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the same thing.

`size` is a function to know the queue dimension. You can write with parenthesis and without them.

You can see [here](http://www.testbench.in/SV_13_QUEUES.html) and [here](http://www.electrosofts.com/systemverilog/arrays.html)

If you have a function without parameter you can ignore parenthesis (your case about size function)

Comment: Does that mean that all functions and tasks can be used w/o parenthesis?

Comment: If a function (like size) has no parameter you can ignore parenthesis. See here: http://books.google.it/books?id=QaWOYTOXy0EC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=systemverilog+function+without+parentheses&source=bl&ots=Z1d-6FEDZN&sig=h9BCQBqBGiUG0S0Uhb-4KSDIdds&hl=it&sa=X&ei=CzN4VJTzE43oaJXwgeAN&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=systemverilog%20function%20without%20parentheses&f=false

Comment: @awill I wouldn't recommend using `queue.size` even though the standard allows it. As you can see, it causes confusion as to whether `size` is a field or function.

Comment: @tudor another one of the random "features" of SystemVerilog that saves almost nothing and gives in return ambiguity and confusion :)